# Is it possible to set the actual SQL that the entity framework provider will execute?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

My entity framework provider (CoreLabs/Mysql/devart) is creating ridiculously slow queries.

is it possible for me to set the actual sql query that will be executed?

Thanks

Comment: Good question: I have used stored procedures within the Entity Framework, but that is with SQL Server.

Comment: I got stored procedures to work in my mysql provider as well.. but the navigational properties on my entities doesnt get populated.

Comment: I want to evaluate devart for Oracle. Can you share what kind of slow queries you experienced. Was it inefficient/bad sql generated by devart ?

Comment: The root cause of the bad queries was the entity framework using EF's inheritance.  It could be EF, it could be devart..   I'm leaning towards EF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its funny, i was just watching [LINQPad - New Features for Entity Framework](http://oreilly.com/pub/e/1295). half way through the webcast, he showed the script generated by the EF and the same query generated by Linq-To-Sql; the linq-to-sql generated script was way more efficient. Now i don't know if using linq-to-sql is an option for you but i thought you should know,

in regards to your question, as i understand the whole point of EF and Linq-to-sql to avoid programmers writing TSQL in strings, doesn't force feeding your own SQL command kind of defeat the whole purpose of EF and Linq-to-sql?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one way is with the [ObjectQuery.ToTraceString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx) API.

Comment: As far as I understood, the author asks how to substitute the SQL query to execute for a particular object query, but not how to read the underlying SQL.

Comment: Sorry, misread that as "see". Yes, if EF v1 you can use stored procs to execute arbitrary SQL. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399203.aspx